# React Native - Network request failed when uploading image second time

Tags: react-native, fetch

I have found what seems to be a bug on Android. I have not tested it on IOS.

`updateProfilePhoto()` is a redux thunk that just sends a PUT request to my node server.

The problem is this, I can upload an image to my node server using fetch. The image is received and saved successfully on the server. If I wait for about 1 second and the upload another image, it goes through successfully. However, if I upload an image and then upload another immediately after the first one goes through, I get the error 'Network request failed' and the second image will not be received on the server.

It seems to me that I cannot constantly upload images back to back really quickly, one will go through, the next one will fail and the next will go through... and so on.

I am testing on an Android Emulator. API level 30. I have not tested on a real device yet, I will try that when I'm able to.

The error happens for the built-in `fetch()` and `XMLHttpRequest`. Both behave the same. On XMLHttpRequest I can check the progress and it says 100% and then fails with `xhr.status` equal to `0`.

I need a sure fire way to upload an image to my server without it failing for no reason. I can add a delay of something like 500ms between uploads and show the user that it's loading but that's a silly way to resolve the issue. I can't find out why the upload fails on the second try.

```
const onSelectProfileImage = (pickerResponse: ImagePickerResponse) =>
    {
        const uri = pickerResponse?.assets && pickerResponse.assets[0].uri;
        const name = pickerResponse?.assets && pickerResponse.assets[0].fileName;
        const type = pickerResponse?.assets && pickerResponse.assets[0].type;

        if(uri)
        {           
            const photo = new FormData();
            photo.append('photo', {name,type,uri});

            dispatch(updateProfilePhoto({photo, uri, user_id: id, headers: {...headers,"content-type": "multipart/form-data"}}))
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check whether your node server is capable to handle multiple overlapping requests

Comment: The request is not even received on the server when the upload issue happens. It's like no request was ever sent. I checked in the place where I verify the JWT

Comment: Still can't find the problem, It has something to do with `react-native-image-picker`. If i dispatch 3 actions in a row, the first one will fail, the second two will pass. I think the issue is with the way i'm choosing the image or something.